# Pop up count down alert with images (android)

Tags: android, popup, countdown

I'm trying to create a countdown timer that will pop up and show a different image every second so it goes "3, 2, 1, Start" then starts a different activity. I've tried this numerous ways but can't get any to work.. if anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be great !

```
package com.practice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Practice2 extends Activity {

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main); 

final long delayCount = 1000;
final long delayIncrement = 1000;
final long delayCount1 = 1000;
final long delayIncrement1 = 1000;
final long delayCount2 = 1000;
final long delayIncrement2 = 1000;


final Dialog dialog = new Dialog (Practice2.this,
android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen); 
dialog.setTitle("Get ready to play DrawTastic!"); 

final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(delayCount, delayIncrement) { 

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

ImageView three = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv3); 
three.setImageResource(R.drawable.three); 

}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ImageView two = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv2); 
two.setImageResource(R.drawable.two); 
timer1.start();
} 

final CountDownTimer timer1 = new CountDownTimer(delayCount1, delayIncrement1) { 

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ImageView one = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv1); 
one.setImageResource(R.drawable.one); 

}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ImageView play = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay); 
play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play); 
timer2.start();
} 

final CountDownTimer timer2 = new CountDownTimer(delayCount2, delayIncrement2) { 

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ImageView play = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay); 
play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play); 

}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ImageView play = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay); 
play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play); 
dialog.dismiss();
}

};
};
};

timer.start();

dialog.show(); 

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). You'll need to show 4 different images at a time interval of 1 second each. Something like -

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.id.nextImage);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

But, I'd suggest you to use `TextView` as shown in API demos.

Go to `Views->TextSwitcher` in API demos.

Comment: When using 'imageView' I get an error. quoting 'it cannot be resolved' - I have attempted to use 'ImageView' also, but resulted in another error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Javaman59 : Thats great! You can upvote so that others will find this answer helpful.